# How to rotate a vector in 3d space? The co ordinate system is not the global xyz. I have the vector for each of the axis of my coordinate system

Tags: math, rotational-matrices

[image: Please click to see image]

I am trying to rotate a vector as shown in the image.The co ordinate system is not the global xyz. I have the vector for each of the axis of my coordinate system.

Comment: create a [transform matrix that represents your coordinate system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) and multiply it by incremental rotation matrix ... than simply transform your vector by it ... another option is to use [Rodrigues_rotation_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) but that is more complicated ...

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the [spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).

General rotation around any 3d axis is trivial when expressed in euclidean coordinates (a matrix) but would be terribly complex expressed in a spherical coordinate system.

Just convert to euclidean, do the rotation and finally convert back.